# Connection between order, connectivity and diameter of a Graph.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Can someone please help me answer this question from my Graph theory course.

I am a little bit stuck.

Let G be a graph with order n and connectivity κ(G) ≥ 1. Let d be the diameter
of G. Prove that
n ≥ κ(G)(d − 1) + 2.

I don't know how to connect the connectivity of a graph with the diameter.